# is Matlab (R2009b) ignoring the transpose operator in "mldivide"?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the linear system of equations A'*x = B using Matlab's "mldivide" (the backslash operator) in the form:

```
x_transp = A'\b;
```

A is a square sparse matrix and that is all I know about it. 
The problem is that the transpose has no effect at all, so the result of the previous line of code is the same than:

```
x = A\b;
```

So, x = x_transp. However, either if I use a new variable such that:

```
A_transp = A';
x_transpOK1 = A_transp\b;
```

or simply use:

```
x_transpOK2 = transp(A)\b;
```

the result is different (x_transpOK1 = x_transpOK2 ≠ x = x_trans).
This behavior occurs in Matlab version 7.9.0 (R2009b) but it does not happen in 7.12 (R2011a).

This, however, does not happen with silly examples I have tried (the behavior then is correct). The matrices that make this behavior arise are:

```
 A =[0.01   -0.495  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0        1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0        0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0        0  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
        0   -0.495  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
        0        0  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
        0        0  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
        0        0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
        0        0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
        0        0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1];

 b =   [8
        4
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0];
```

Is it some kind of precision issue? Am I making any fundamental error I cannot see?

Comment: Just `try x = (A')\B`

Comment: Also does not happen in R2010a.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau Unfortunately, it still ignores the transpose operator that way. Also using brackets and also putting the transpose outside the parenthesis or brackets.

Comment: It doesn't happen to me (R2010b) with the example you provide

Comment: Are you sure it ignores that transpose operator. Have you compared the results from `(A')\b` (or `A'\b`) with the results from `transp(A)\b`. Or even better, created an example like `A=[1,0;1,1], b = [1;1]` which can really easily be calculated by hand and compared the result? The result from my example will give `x = [0;1]` given the equation `(A')*x=b`.

Comment: @patrik  No, of course I am not sure it ignores the transpose. In fact, as I pointed out in the question, I tried small examples and the results are as expected (Matlab does the transpose). But in the example matrices I show, the transpose operator (either with or without parenthesis or brackets) has no effect (but `transp` does).

Comment: @Mario_Exec.bat The reason that I ask is the error cannot be reproduced in matlab 2013a that I use and I seriously doubt that this bug does only occur in certain situations. This is an important operator and I doubt that this error would go unnoticed. Have you done the comparison `nnz((transp(A)\b) - (A'\b))`? this will be larger than `0` if the functions are not the same. Further have you tried to run your example? The code does not compile for me due to the commas. I guess that everyone will know what you mean, but I just wonder if you have tried the code and got the error described.

Comment: Huh.  I tried a new random A matrix and everything is as expected. It has to be something to do with your A matrix specifically. (2009b)

Comment: Huh. `A'\b`, `(A')\b`, `pinv(A)*b` provide the same result. `transpose(A)\b`, `mldivide(A',b)`, `mldivide(transpose(A),b)` provide the same result (and diff than the first set).  I tried a new random A matrix and everything is as expected. It has to be something to do with your A matrix specifically. (2009b)

Comment: @patrik I have double checked that with the example I provide the error can be reproduced. 
I have also changed the commas to periods so that anyone can directly try it. 
Yes, I tried the comparison you suggest and it returns 0 (same matrix).

Comment: @brechmos Yes, I am also thinking that the problem is related to those specific matrices but I cannot figure it out the cause.

Comment: I don't get something... for me `nnz((transpose(A)\b) - (A'\b)) = 3`. I ck'ed A and b and they are the same as what you have in the original post.

Comment: Found some discussion of precision in these cases... http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/324128  might be of help.

Comment: @Mario_Exec.bat if my comparison returns `0` it means that A'\b gives the expected output. It is most likely that the error comes from somewhere else in the code. One question: did you use complex numbers when you got the error? The operator `'` gives the hermitian transpose. If you do not want the hermitian transpose you must use `.'`.

Comment: Ok, stupid question people. I don't have transp(), I do have transpose(). Where are you finding transp in your matlab path?  Or am I just missing something stupid :-).  (for me transpose -> matlab79/toolbox/matlab/ops/@logical/transpose).

Comment: @brechmos I think that all people talk about `transpose` :). I do not remember what it were called in R2009.

Comment: @patrik: ok, thought I was losing it :-)

Comment: Now I am obsessing. `C=A'` and then `C\b` is different than `A'\b`. But `nnz(C-A')=0`.

Comment: It appears @patrik has a point. `A.'` and `A'` visually produce the same matrix but somehow mldivide seems to be interpreting them differently. `A.' = transpose(A)` and is the non-conjugate transpose of A.  `A'` is the complex conjugate transpose.  Ah, so maybe mldivide looks to see if the input is "complex" or not and uses a different algorithm internally.  (not completely sure on this, just a thought).

Comment: @patrik Sorry, my eyes went somewhere else and I did the wrong comparison. For me `nnz((nnz((transp(A)\b) - (A'\b)) = 3` just like @brechmos. 

No, I am not using any complex numbers, just the ones of the example I put and there is no more code (I clean the environment, copy the examples I put in the question, and that strange behavior is still happening). As there are no complex numbers, I guess that `transp` (which is the same as `.'`) and `transpose` (which is the same as `'`) should give me the same matrix. In fact: `nnz(transp(A)-transpose(A))=0`.

Comment: @Mario_Exec.bat, it seems to me that you might want to take this to the Matlab Answers (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/) as maybe someone with knowledge of the actual code (ie a Matlab employee) might be able to help you more specifically. It is an interesting question but it seems there is more going on that might need more knowledge of the actual code and decision trees.

Comment: Sorry again @patrik and @brechmos, I was wrong. `transp` seems to be the same as `transpose`, and thus, the same as `.'`([see this](http://dali.feld.cvut.cz/ucebna/matlab/toolbox/mutools/cjt.html)). 

So, as a summary, in MATLAB (R2009b), for this example (no complex numbers), the following cases are happening: A'\b = A\b; (Wrong results)|| A'\b ≠ A.'\b; (A.'\b is OK)||C = A'; C\b = A.'\b; (OK)|| transpose(A)\b = ctranspose(A)\b = A.'\b;(OK)||A' = ctranspose(A) = A.' = tranpose(A);(OK).

I agree with you in that it is related to decisions on Matlab internal code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Should you write an answer (saying the same as here), so that I can vote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guys at Mathworks replied: it is a bug in the interpreter, which have been fixed in the next versions. There is no fix for 7.9.0 and they recommend the following workaround:

```
A_transp = A';
x = A_transp\b;
```

I guess this is a great example of the typical advice to always be up-to-date...

[My original post on Matlab Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/135166-is-matlab-r2009b-ignoring-the-transpose-operator-in-mldivide#answer_141583)

[The bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/583443)

Answer (score 0):

After all the discussion, here is my answer:

@Mario_Exec.bat, it seems to me that you might want to take this to the Matlab Answers (mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers) as maybe someone with knowledge of the actual code (ie a Matlab employee) might be able to help you more specifically. It is an interesting question but it seems there is more going on that might need more knowledge of the actual code and decision trees.

Please do post back here when you hear back. I am curious what they say!